# How to solve $9\sin 2x-40\cos 2x=\frac{41}{\sqrt{2}}$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve the following question:

> \begin{eqnarray}
> \\9\sin 2x-40\cos 2x&=&\frac{41}{\sqrt{2}}\\
> \end{eqnarray}

I know that there is a formula for solving the above question like :

> \begin{eqnarray}
> \cos a=\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} , \space\space
> \sin a=\frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} \\
> \\A\sin 2x-B\cos 2x=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\cos \left(x-a\right)\\
> \end{eqnarray}

If I do not use this formula, how can I solve the above question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $9=r\cos y,40=r\sin y$ where $y>0$

Squaring & adding we get $\displaystyle  r^2=1681=41^2\implies r=41$

$\displaystyle \cos y=\frac9r=\frac9{41},\sin y=\frac{40}{41}$

$\displaystyle\implies 9\cos2x-40\sin2y=\frac{41}{\sqrt2}\iff\cos2x\cos y-\sin2x\sin y=\frac1{\sqrt2}$

$\displaystyle\implies \cos(2x+\arccos\frac9{41})=\frac1{\sqrt2}=\cos\frac\pi4$

$\displaystyle\implies 2x+\arccos\frac9{41}=2n\pi\pm\frac\pi4$ where $n$ is an integer

Comment: The answer can be $x=\frac{n\pi }{2}+\left(-1\right)^n\frac{\pi }{8}+\frac{\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{40}{41}\right)}{2}$. Right?

Comment: @CasperLi, which is same as $$x=n\pi\pm\frac\pi8+\frac{\cos^{-1}\frac9{41}}2$$ as $$\cos^{-1}\frac9{41}=\sin^{-1}\frac{40}{41}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \sin{x} + \dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \cos{x} \right)\\
=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\sin{\varphi} \sin{x} + \cos{\varphi} \cos{x} \right)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos{(x-\varphi)},$$
where
$$\sin{\varphi} =\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}, \\
\cos{\varphi} =\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) namely, $$\sin2x=\frac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2x}\text{ and }\cos2x=\frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}$$ to form a Quadratic Equation in $\tan x$

and $\tan x=\tan\alpha\implies x=n\pi+\alpha$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: How to derive $\sin 2x=\frac{2\tan x}{1+\tan ^2x}$ and $\cos x=\frac{1-\tan ^2x}{1+\tan ^2x}$ from the original formulas? Or Are there any easy way to remember these two formulas?

Comment: @CasperLi, http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081106094912AAwnY0Z